# Prevent autocomplete selection with enter in VS Code's Debug Console

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm finding the behaviour of VS Code's Debug Console auto-complete incredibly frustrating, due to its very strong preference for finding any kind of autocomplete, no matter how tangentially related to what I actually typed.

In the editor, I have "Accept Suggestion On Enter" disabled. However, I can't find an equivalent setting for the Debug Console.

Is there a way to disable it? Preferably, just disabling auto-complete-on-enter, but failing that, disabling all autocomplete would be better than nothing.

EDIT

The issue was tracked here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code now has a setting for what you are asking for: Debug › Console: Accept Suggestion On Enter.